# Problems analyzing and saving file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a problem using this line `File.foreach ('ojo.txt'). with_object ([]) do | line, result |` to go line by line of a file because I need it to decipher the first three characters of a file purchase order. my problem is the following at the time of saving and I am inside this cycle `do` saves me empty records ... and there comes a time in the analyises that example:

```
LIN00000100635818000159EN 
IMDF  CU VINO S  EMA 14.5G CATAL PREM BOT 75
QTY 21000000000000001SIN
QTY129000000000000001SIN
MOA203000000000016338.00
PRIAAA000000021498.00LIUSIN
ALCA  DE1
PCD  10000024.00
MOA204000000000005160.00
ALCC  CA1
MOA 23000000000000180.00
```

those are the lines to analyze use `if line.start_with? ('LIN')` and then decode. but those six 11 lines I want to analyze together because in a file there X quantity of products in a few words is repeated many times. the way I'm doing it, only the first article keeps me, the others do not.

additionally I would like to generate a report with a record and the detail of that record in a somewhat simple way if possible. I'm new to ruby.

I attach my code and see could you help me.

```
            File.foreach('ojo.txt').with_object([]) do |line, result|
             if lines.start_with?('LIN')
                @cproducto = lines[8..-2]
             end
                if lines.start_with?('IMD')
                   @desproducto = lines[8..-1]
                end
            if lines.start_with?('QTY 21')                      
                   @cantidadpedida = lines[-5..-4]              
                   caja = lines[-3..-1]
                   if caja = ('CSC')
                      @tcaja = 'cajas de carton'
                   end
                   if pedido = ('CS')
                      @tcaja= 'cajas'
                   end
                   if pedido = ('SIN')
                      @tcaja= 'Uunidades Simples'
                   end
                   if pedido = ('KGM')
                      @tcaja= 'Kilogramos'
                   end
            end       
            if lines.start_with?('QTY129')
               @cantidadunidades = lines[-6..-4]                               
               @tunidad = 'Unidades Simples'
            end                         
            if lines.start_with?('MOA 203')                
               @precio = 'Precio neto'
               @precioneto = lines[-10..-1]
            end
            if lines.start_with?('MOA 23')                 
               @tcargo = 'Cargo'
               @valorcargo = lines[-10..-1]
            end
            if lines.start_with?('MOA 203')                
               @precio = 'Precio neto'
               @precioneto = lines[-10..-1]
            end
            if lines.start_with?('MOA 204')                
               @tdescu = 'Descuento'
               @valordescu = lines[-10..-1]
            end

            if lines.start_with?('PRIAAA')
                  pedido = lines[-3..-1]
                  @valorcd = lines[-16..-8]                            
               if pedido = ('CSC')
                  @tcaja2 = 'cajas de carton'
               end
               if pedido = 'CS'
                  @tcaja2 = 'cajas'
               end                              
            end

               if lines.start_with?('ALCA') and (lines.include?('DE1') or lines.include?('DE2'))
                  @cdescuento = 'DESCUENTO'              
               end  
               if lines.start_with?('ALCC') and (lines.include?('CA1') or lines.include?('CA1'))            
                  @ccargo = 'CARGO'         
               end  

               if lines.start_with?('PCD') and (lines[5] = '1')                       
                  porcentaje = lines[-6..-1]
                  @porecentaje = 'porcentaje de descuento'
               else
                  @porecentaje = 'porcentaje del cargo'
               end  

            if lines.start_with?('MOA 86')
               clave     = lines[0..2]              
               importe = lines[-9..-1]               

            end
            if lines.start_with?('CNT')                             
               @items2 = lines[-2..-1]      
            end
end
       Detalles2s.create(descrip: @desproducto, tipebox: @tcaja , cantidad: @cantidadunidades,  tipounidad: @tunidad , precio: @precio, precioneto: @precioneto)
```

something like that to analyze the lines but that does not work

```
if line.start_with?('LIN') and not line.start_with?('IMD') and lines.start_with?('QTY 21') and  lines.start_with?('QTY129') and lines.start_with?('MOA 203') and (lines.start_with?('MOA 204') or lines.start_with?('MOA 23')) and lines.start_with?('PRIA') and lines.start_with?('PCD') and (lines.start_with?('ALCA') or lines.start_with?('ALCC'))
```

Comment: As a first step, run ruby with the `-w` option, and correct all the `warning: found = in conditional, should be ==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many consecutive `if`'s testing the same thing is wasting CPU time because if a line starts with `LIN`, the other `if`'s will be executed but never be true. A case statement stops comparing as soon as a `when`clause is satisfyied.

DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself. You have two times `if pedido == ('CS')`. All tests about `pedido` are better grouped in one place, this makes the maintenance of the program easier on the long term.

There are many ways to do things in Ruby. The following program gives you one taste of what the solution could be.

```
class Detalles2s
    attr_accessor :cproducto, :cantidadunidades, :desproducto, :precio,
                  :precioneto, :tcaja, :tunidad

    def analyze
        File.foreach('ojo.txt') do | line |
            line = line.chomp # remove CrLf (\r\n)
            puts "processing line #{line} ..."

            case
            when line.start_with?('LIN')
                @cproducto = line[8..-2]
                puts "@cproducto=#{@cproducto}"
            when line.start_with?('IMD')
                @desproducto = line[8..-1]
            when line.start_with?('QTY 21')                      
                @cantidadpedida = line[-5..-4]              
                caja   = line[-3..-1]
                pedido = '?????????????????????'
                @tcaja = unitOfMeasure(pedido)
            when line.start_with?('QTY129')
                @cantidadunidades = line[-6..-4]                               
                @tunidad = 'Unidades Simples'
            when line.start_with?('MOA203') # not ('MOA 203')                
                @precio = 'Precio neto'
                @precioneto = line[7..-1] # not [-10..-1]
            when line.start_with?('MOA 23')                 
                @tcargo = 'Cargo'
                @valorcargo = line[-10..-1]
            when line.start_with?('MOA 204')                
                @tdescu = 'Descuento'
                @valordescu = line[-10..-1]
            when line.start_with?('PRIAAA')
                pedido = line[-3..-1]
                @valorcd = line[-16..-8]                            
                @tcaja2  = unitOfMeasure(pedido)
            when (line.start_with?('ALCA') and (line.include?('DE1') or line.include?('DE2')))
                @cdescuento = 'DESCUENTO'              
            when line.start_with?('ALCC') && (line.include?('CA1') || line.include?('CA1'))            
                @ccargo = 'CARGO'         
            when line.start_with?('PCD')
                if line[5] == '1'
                then
                    porcentaje   = line[-6..-1] # not used !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    @porecentaje = 'porcentaje de descuento'
                else
                    @porecentaje = 'porcentaje del cargo'
                end  
            when line.start_with?('MOA 86')
                clave   = line[0..2]              
                importe = line[-9..-1]               
            when line.start_with?('CNT')                             
                @items2 = line[-2..-1]
            else
                puts 'starts with something else'
            end
        end # foreach
    end # analyze

    def unitOfMeasure(p_pedido)
        case p_pedido
        when 'CS'  then 'cajas'
        when 'CSC' then 'cajas de carton'
        when 'SIN' then 'Unidades Simples'
        when 'KGM' then 'Kilogramos'
        else
            puts "bad unit #{p_pedido}"
            'undefined'
        end
    end
end #class Detalles2s

un_producto = Detalles2s.new
un_producto.analyze
p un_producto
puts "cproducto=#{un_producto.cproducto}"
puts "desproducto=#{un_producto.desproducto}"
puts "tcaja=#{un_producto.tcaja}"
puts "cantidadunidades=#{un_producto.cantidadunidades}"
puts "tunidad=#{un_producto.tunidad}"
puts "precio=#{un_producto.precio}"
puts "precioneto=#{un_producto.precioneto}"
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
t.rb:18: warning: assigned but unused variable - caja
t.rb:44: warning: assigned but unused variable - porcentaje
t.rb:50: warning: assigned but unused variable - clave
t.rb:51: warning: assigned but unused variable - importe
processing line LIN00000100635818000159EN  ...
@cproducto=100635818000159EN
processing line IMDF  CU VINO S  EMA 14.5G CATAL PREM BOT 75 ...
processing line QTY 21000000000000001SIN ...
bad unit ?????????????????????
processing line QTY129000000000000001SIN ...
processing line MOA203000000000016338.00 ...
processing line PRIAAA000000021498.00LIUSIN ...
processing line ALCA  DE1 ...
processing line PCD  10000024.00 ...
processing line MOA204000000000005160.00 ...
starts with something else
processing line ALCC  CA1 ...
processing line MOA 23000000000000180.00 ...
#<Detalles2s:0x007f90dfa1cbe8 @cproducto="100635818000159EN", @desproducto=" VINO S  EMA 14.5G CATAL PREM BOT 75", @cantidadpedida="01", @tcaja="undefined", @cantidadunidades="001", @tunidad="Unidades Simples", @precio="Precio neto", @precioneto="00000000016338.00", @valorcd="0021498.0", @tcaja2="Unidades Simples", @cdescuento="DESCUENTO", @porecentaje="porcentaje de descuento", @ccargo="CARGO", @tcargo="Cargo", @valorcargo="0000180.00">
cproducto=100635818000159EN
desproducto= VINO S  EMA 14.5G CATAL PREM BOT 75
tcaja=undefined
cantidadunidades=001
tunidad=Unidades Simples
precio=Precio neto
precioneto=00000000016338.00
```

Comment: hello @bernarkk before nothing thanks for your time ... works the command line because it shows me what it has loaded in the terminal but I do not work the save function since in the database does not reflect anything change the .new by .create and says undefined method

Comment: If you have the source code of class `Detalles2s`, you have to `def self.create`. I probably can't help with a DB, I haven't used one since 40 years. You can't avoid learning enough Ruby to do yourself what you desire to achieve. Nobody will write the whole program for you. If you have a specific problem, you can ask a question, see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: hello please check the update of the question, analyze me the others but only save the first. and of course I understand I'm not looking for the code but a little guidance until an idea serves to unlock my mind in relation to ruby

Comment: _check the update of the question_ Which update ? I don't see an edit of your post. You English is hard to understand (_analyze me the others_, _I'm not looking for the code_). I suggest to try `https://translate.google.com`or ask for help. If you are not able to write in a file/DB, post a question with the minimum of code that you have tried and does not work. Again, SO is not a coding service.